# Troubles to move turtlebot_gazebo

Tags: c++, geometry, ros, robotics

I started a small project where I wanted to move the turtlebot in gazebo. I launched: roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_world.launch

I wrote a code to move it:

```
#include "ros/ros.h" 
#include "geometry_msgs/TwistWithCovariance.h" 
#include "nav_msgs/Odometry.h" 
#include "gazebo_msgs/LinkState.h" 
#include "geometry_msgs/Twist.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv){

ros::init(argc,argv,"move");
ros::NodeHandle n;
ros::Publisher move_pub = n.advertise<geometry_msgs::Twist>("moving",1000);
ros::Rate loop_rate(10);

geometry_msgs::Twist msg;
while(ros::ok()){
    msg.linear.x = 0.0;
    msg.linear.y = 0.0;
    msg.linear.z = 20.0;
    move_pub.publish(msg);

    ros::spinOnce();

    loop_rate.sleep();

    }

}
```

This doesn't work. As you can see i included other msgs and tried it with them but I got the same result. I also tried to find the node turtlebot_teleop_keyboard to find out how it is done by inputs. But i couldn't find the path to it. So what do I have to do to move it? And how can I find the path to the node?

Answer (score 2):

You are publishing to wrong topic, and wrong parameters.

1- After launching your turtlebot, type "rostopic list" from another terminal and look for topics that contain cmd_vel or cmd_vel_mux. If there is not cmd_vel_mux just publish cmd_vel, otherwise publish one of cmd_vel_mux/input.

2- For Turtlebot's linear movement, only x has any effect.

Example node in my ros-kinetic:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    ros::init(argc,argv,"move");
    ros::NodeHandle n;
    ros::Publisher move_pub = n.advertise<geometry_msgs::Twist>("/cmd_vel_mux/input/navi",1000);
    ros::Rate loop_rate(10);

    geometry_msgs::Twist msg;
    while(ros::ok())
    {
        //  linear velocity
        msg.linear.x = 1.0;
        msg.linear.y = 0.0;
        msg.linear.z = 0.0;

        //  angular velocity
        msg.angular.x = 0.0;
        msg.angular.y = 0.0;
        msg.angular.z = 0.0;

        move_pub.publish(msg);

        ros::spinOnce();

        loop_rate.sleep();
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the mux standing for? And if I want to do something else, how do I know which topic I have to publish?

Comment: Sorry for late response, [cmd_vel_mux](http://wiki.ros.org/cmd_vel_mux) is a special ros topic that used to determine which input is going to be priotized (for example, you may want your teleop commands to override other command when both of them active, or your superior's controller might override your commands etc). Mux stands for multiplexer.
In order to know which topic to use for moving your robot, best thing to do is find your robot on ros wiki. If it is a robot with wheel, most likely it is going to have cmd_vel, but different robots may use different input systems (legs, arms...).

Answer (score 0):

For Turtlebot, you have topics to publish linear velocities - x, y and z and also angular velocities - x, y and z. What you need to understand is what each of these physically mean.

**Linear velocity in x will make it move forward.**

**Angular velocity in z will make it turn about itself.**

Other parameters don't do anything.
So, in your code, using the above 2 parameters will move the bot. Rest of the parameters won't affect the bot in any way.